# How do I update all attributes of a class in IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

Objective:

I would like to reset the array attribute of all objects in a class to []. The way they started.

My attempt:

```
> Deal.find(:all).update_attribute('votes', [])
```

Outcome:

Returns an error. How would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because find(:all) returns an array.

You can do:

```
Deal.update_all :votes => []
```

or

```
Deal.all.each { |d| d.update_attribute(:votes, []) }
```

if you need something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
Deal.update_all :votes => []
```